# iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notifications using Ionic 4 not working

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am developing a cross-platform application, which requires the use of Push Notifications for both Android and iOS. I am currently using the latest Cordova plugin I've discovered for firebase-cloud messaging: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated, which works flawlessly for Android but does not improve my situation with iOS.

I've also done the following:

1. Check Xcode console if the connection to FCM is successful
2. Check if subscription to the desired topic is successful
3. Added com.google.fcm to Url Types in Xcode
4. Readded both Push Notifications and Background Mode (Remote Notifications) in Capabilities in XCode

I have the following code to set up Push Notifications, which works for Android:

```
this.fcm.subscribeToTopic(`my-desired-topic`);

    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(msg => {
      if (this.platform.is("ios")) {
        this.showAlert(msg.aps.title, msg.aps.alert, [
          "/notifications",
          id
        ]);

        console.log(msg.aps);
      } else {
        this.showAlert(msg.title, msg.body, ["/notifications", this.eventId]);
        console.log(msg);
      }



      if (msg.wasTapped) {
        this.router.navigate(["/notifications", id]);
        console.log("Received in background");
      } else {
        // this.router.navigate(["/notifications", id]);
        console.log("Received in foreground");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I solved it by reuploading the APNS Auth Key (Generated using the apple account) with the correct Key-ID and Team-ID in the Firebase Console->Project Settings-Cloud Messaging->iOS Configuration next to the previously mentioned steps. Another thing that helped is to clear project build folder just before running the app on the device and archiving, which takes the latest url types in consideration. Hope this helps others that may be wondering why their PNs don't work on iOS.